# Is it formally grammatical to just put "For example + noun phrases" and call it a sentence?

Tags: sentence

I got to see some English learners' writing works, and they often write like this:

a) *My favorite foods are Japanese foods. For example, sushi, miso soup, and octopus balls.*

For me, this sounds a bit strange, and I'm thinking of either one of the following corrections:

b) *My favorite foods are Japanese foods: for example, sushi, miso soup, and octopus balls.*
c) *My favorite foods are Japanese foods. For example, I like sushi, miso soup, and octopus balls.*

They are beginning learners and I'm not sure if they can handle punctuations like colons, so I'm inclined to the second correction (c).

As a non-native speaker of English, I'd like your advise on whether (a) is correct and which of (b) and (c) is better.

Thank you.

Comment: Two minor suggestions on how to improve your English expression in the question: (1) "advise" is a verb, but your sentence requires the noun form "advice"; (2) "punctuation" can be used as a countable noun but I would be more inclined to use treat it as uncountable in this context. PS are you aware of our sibling site [ell.se]? Might be worth searching for advice on sentence fragments.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I did not know about that site. I'll try searching that forum for future questions.

Answer (score 2):

I say that a) is fine.  You may argue that the second part is a sentence fragment, not a sentence.  But in speaking and writing, we often use sentence fragments.  And therefore, English learners should learn about them.